# Сборка WAR файла

Tags: ant, java

Здравствуйте.

Дайте, пожалуйста, пример сборки WAR-файла при помощи Apache Ant. Например, одной jsp-страницы, одного сервлета и библиотек.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="projectWar" default="make.war">
    <!--
      струкура:
      lib/   -> либы проекта
      res/projectWar/index.jsp     -> файлы ресурсов

      res/projectWar/WEB-INF/web.xml -> файл web.xml
      src/          -> исходники

      результат: build/lib/projectWar.war  
    -->
    <property name="lib.classpath" value="lib/"/>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>
    <path id="project.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.classpath}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
    </path>
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" classpathref="project.classpath" debug="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    </target>
    <target name="make.war" depends="clean,compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/lib"/>
        <war destfile="build/lib/${ant.project.name}.war" webxml="res/${ant.project.name}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <classes dir="build/classes"/>
            <fileset dir="res/${ant.project.name}/">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
            <lib dir="${lib.classpath}"/>
        </war>
    </target>
</project>
```

Вызов в консоли:

```
ant
```

Answer (score 0):

Из консоли можно сделать так:

```
jar cf appName.war /www
```

Где: appName.war - имя будущего пакета, /www - каталог со скомпилированным проектом.